# Fazer um javascript funcionar dentro de uma URL

Tags: php, javascript, html

O código javascript abaixo funciona perfeitamente no HTML do meu site. Ele é um servidor geo-target que mostra a cidade baseado no IP do usuário.

```
<script src='http://promos.fling.com/geo/txt/location.php?testip='></script>
```

O que estou querendo fazer e não consigo é fazê-lo funcionar dentro de um link que pretendo que seja gerado de acordo com a cidade da pessoa. Tipo:

```
<a href="http://www.example.net/?q=Belo Horizonte">Belo Horizonte</a>
```

Eu tentei fazer funcionar da maneira abaixo mas a resposta ao final da URL, após `?q=` é o próprio código. Tentei desta forma:

```
<a href="http://www.example.net/?q=<script src='http://promos.fling.com/geo/txt/location.php?testip='></script>">Belo Horizonte</a>
```

Eu sou um pouco leigo nesse assunto portanto qualquer solução seja ela em PHP ou javascript seria bem vinda. Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer, ou melhor: o que deve acontecer quando o usuário clica no link? Essa deteção está a ser feita em PHP?, podes colocar esse código de geo-target aqui?

Answer (score 1):

Se percebi o que queres fazer, tens que fazer algo do género:

```
    <a id="link" href="http://www.example.net/?q="></a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        getContent("http://promos.fling.com/geo/txt/location.php?testip=", function(code) {
            // code = 'document.write("lisbon")'; -> selecionar só a cidade
            code = code.substring(code.indexOf("\"")+1, code.lastIndexOf("\""));
            var lnk = document.getElementById('link');
            lnk.href += code;
            lnk.text = code;
        });

        function getContent( url, callBackFunction )
        {
             // attempt to create the XMLHttpRequest and make the request
             try
             {
                var asyncRequest; // variable to hold XMLHttpRequest object
                asyncRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); // create request object

                // register event handler
                asyncRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    stateChange(asyncRequest, callBackFunction);
                } 
                asyncRequest.open( 'GET', url, true );  // prepare the request
                asyncRequest.send( null );              // send the request
             } // end try
             catch ( exception )
             {
                alert( 'Request failed.' );
             } // end catch
        } // end function getContent
    </script>
```